# Unit Test log in redirected to correct url - Redirect of a button click event

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, buttonclick

I have a button click event which on successful login calls a private method, which in turn redirects the user to a page depending on the user's role. I am testing if a user of a particular role is redirected properly to the page. Please help me test this.

```
    public void LogonUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool expired;
            String userName;
            UserAuthentication userAuth = new UserAuthentication();

            userAuth.GetUserLoginInfo(UserID.Value, out userName, out expired);

          string returnUrl = Request.QueryString[PhysicianProfileAppConstants.QueryStringKeys.ReturnUrl];
            if (SuperUserControllerAttribute.IsSuperUserController(returnUrl)
                && !this.currentUserService.GetCurrentUser().IsSuperUser)
            {
                this.MissingSuperUserDiv.Visible = true;
                return;
            }

                 if (!CheckForceChangeFormVisibility(expired))
                {
                    OnSuccessfullLogin();
                }

        }


 private void OnSuccessfullLogin()
        {
            var userInfo = this.userEntityService.GetUserByLoginId(userId);
            if (userInfo.IsSelfService == true)
            {
                if (userInfo.Physicians.Count() == 1)
                {
                    var url = "/" + userInfo.Physicians.First().Id;
                    Response.Redirect(url);
                }

                }
            Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] ?? FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
        }
```

Comment: It rather looks like an integration test. What about using Selenium here?

Answer (score 1):

Separate your domain logic from your UI - see e.g. http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx for a detailed discussion.  With this approach, your button click will just call a method in another class, a "presenter", that's isolated from the UI details, that you can then easily unit test.  To make sure your UI is wired up correctly to your presenter, you can use an automated integration test using something like Selenium, or use a manual smoke test, since this approach makes the UI code so simple it's unlikely to be broken once you have it working.